# Async tcp protocol in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, asynchronous, tcp, protocols

I'm about to implement a server-client protocol over TCP with the following features:

1. Request and response functionality
2. Authentication
3. Server side initiated messages

All over one single TCP connection.

Each request and response will contain multiple variables such as in a HTTP POST request but there might be a need for more nested structures, perhaps some object serialization.

I have an idea of how to implement this from the ground up.

My question, is there any existing protocol, preferably with helpful functions in c# that does this?

Also this will be implemented in c# but a protocol that just as easily can get implemented in other languages is a plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try and useWCF, which supports communication over TCP

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I have started to take a look at it, however some things are not clear yet.
Can messages be initiated both ways?

Comment: You want to google WCF and 'Duplex Contracts' for bi-directional communications